# Postgres: syntax, identifiers, instructions

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to understand whether there is an instruction, like the MySQL's `USE`, to choose a database, once created from Java.

I would like at first to access the dbms via the url `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/` (without database), so I would insert an instruction to create the db, and so another instruction to use/choose it.

I am building a function that is supposed to connect to dbms, create a database, use it, and finally delete it (as I need temporary data: I tried H2 In Memory but it didn't work in my specific application).

I have been able to realize such a behavior with MySQL, but unluckily I cannot use MySQL; my code for this was:

```
manager.setJDBCDriver("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
manager.setJDBCUsername("root");
manager.setJDBCPassword("mypass");
manager.setJDBCUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/");
manager.createConnection();
manager.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE " + database);
manager.executeUpdate("USE " + database);
```

Where I will put the database deletion query in a module calling this latter code.

I would like to do so even with PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `use` when using JDBC, instead you should be using `setCatalog` and `setSchema` (which you need to use depends on the database, driver and type of object).

For MySQL the equivalent of `use` is `setCatalog`, see [Driver/Datasource Class Names, URL Syntax and Configuration Properties for Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html):

> Always use the `Connection.setCatalog()` method to specify the desired
>   database in JDBC applications, rather than the `USE database`
>   statement.

Unfortunately, the PostgreSQL JDBC driver doesn't support switching to another database. You will need to disconnect and create a new connection.

Comment: hello! commands never seen before, now i will have a look.. thanks

Comment: by the way, maybe i don't have to switch, but to create and destroy, in each of my application execution, the same db: after the execution of 'manager.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE " + database)', what is the command to do as you have said, by connecting to the newly created db and immediately disconnecting when no more utilizable? sorry if i don't get the point, i am not so good with english